# Windows 7 will not update

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I have just received my brand new computer, and have just installed Windows 7 Pro 64-bit with the necessary drivers, and all. Now I want to run Windows update, but it fails saying that the service is not running.

However, running `services.mcs` I can see that `Background Intelligent Transfer Service` *and* `Windows Update` are both set to `Automatic (Delayed Start` (as they should). I have tried reseting the "Windows Update Settings" and even running [this scripts](http://www.sevenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/261410-windows-7-will-not-update.html) (and restarting... whatever). Nothing works and I always get the same error.

Any help appreciated.

#### ** Edit **

If I change the Windows Update Settings (to any value), nothing happens when I click "Check for updates". After Windows restarts, it goes back to the "Service not running" error message.

#### ** Update **

Here is a screen cap of the error message.[image]

**NOTE**: as I wrote, the services *are* running! Changing the "Windows update settings" to any value makes the error disappear... but also nothing happens. The error is displayed whenever I try to update after a restart.

#### ** Update 2 **

Running MS WU did not find anything O_o

[image]

Comment: 1) Have you confirmed your computer time (and timezone) are correct?  2) Have you tried the [MS WU fixit](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/windows_update/) yet?  3) What's the exact error message and error code you get?  4) What do the Event Logs say about it?

Comment: The date and time are correct. I will paste a screen capture of the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered this once or twice. The solution for me was deleting the contents of `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution`:

1) Stop BITS and Windows Update (and make sure they weren't automatically restarted).

2) Make backup of `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution`.

3) Delete contents of `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution`, the folder itself shall remain existing.

4) Start BITS and Windows Update.

5) Start update. (The first run will take a hell of a time, so don't panic.)

6) If everything is OK, you can delete the backup from (2).

Comment: You rule! That worked! I don't know what was in the old copy... I've never started Windows Update before... (vanilla install!). Anyhow. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. :)
Windows sometimes somehow break its update log and then this happens.

Comment: I only install Windows to play games... and it's been about a year since I tooled with it (I'm not a gamer!) It always fascinates me how people can cope and endure from this OS.