# windows 7 does not update

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, updates

Today I clean-installed windows-7 64bit. Everything is fine, but Windows Update does not run well. It told me that update for Windows Update should be installed first. So I pressed `Install update` but there is just infinite `Checking for updates...`.

I tried solution from this topic - [Windows 7 will not update](https://superuser.com/questions/751717/windows-7-will-not-update)

But when I run checking for updates it is still just checking, seems never-ending. I can't even install some apps (MS Visual studio stops on update KB2882822). But, some updates were installed yet, when I list installed updates there are 6 updates installed.

Can somebody help me with it.

Comment: The accepted answer to the linked question specifically says that "The first run will take a hell of a time, so don't panic.". "Infinite" is pretty long; how long have you waited, and what kind of Internet connection are you on?

Comment: Have to tried waiting, perhaps overnight?

Comment: Most W7 systems I have reinstalled initially take 1 to 1.5 hours before it finds updates and populates the page.

Comment: It searched updates yet, but still doesn't downloaded single KB after 2 - 2.5 hours.. still waiting

Comment: And what is interesting my disk space is still smaller and smaller. Updater said that here are 900MB of updates. My disk free space is about 900MB smaller than before 2 hours

Comment: Sorry a forgot about this question. Problem was in windows activation. I thought that windows will automatically activate itself when I entered serial key during installation but it doesn't. So I manually clicked Activate Windows and than after some time (It also took some time) it updated normally. ..my fault..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically when I have a fresh system of a less than freshly released OS with a ton of patches, I tend to hit it with a copy of [wsus offline update](http://download.wsusoffline.net/). Run the updater and it builds an offline update pack of all the current/necessary updates. Then run it and it installs. This should include the update for windows update (which i seem to recall works from way back). And you can update the update pack periodically and reuse it for other systems or your next rebuild.

[image]

its super simple, and in my experience, tends to get a system up quick. It will make an initial, large download but otherwise its pretty painless. In your shoes I'd pick the USB medium option, pick a local directory to download the updates to, wait for it to download, then run the installer there.

Comment: Why didnt I know about this tool earlier... damn its great!! +1

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft released a new WindowsUpdate Client Update to fix the slow Update searching/Installation.

**Installing and searching for updates is slow and high CPU usage occurs in Windows 7**
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3102810

**Download:**
**32Bit:** http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=fcd6bf5d-f004-4ca3-aa7e-1de462b91dd0

**64Bit:** http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=4fe566bd-31b1-4413-8c4c-412b52533669

Try this new Update and look if it speeds up the installation of Updates.